# Regex split mac OSX output in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to split the output of the `df -h` command which appears in a Mac OSX log file, the line looks like:

```
//user@192.168.0.10/share  3.6Ti  1.0Ti  2.7Ti    28% 264402606  712347471   27%   /private/tmp/mount something here
```

What I need is the output

```
//user@192.168.0.10/share
3.6Ti
1.0Ti
2.7Ti
28%
264402606
712347471
27%
/private/tmp/mount something here
```

I'm having trouble splitting this due to the spaces appearing in the final entry, so I'm not quite sure how to handle this.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

--Updated--

Thanks for all the input, this is the solution I figured out:

```
var fields = Regex.Split(line, @"[ ]{2,}|(?<=\d+\%?)\s+(?=\d+\%?)")?.ToList();
```

I'll take a look at the proposed answers, thanks

Comment: how constant or variable is the structure of this line? which parts remain constant and which can change? and in what fashion?

Comment: The structure will always be the same,  but the values can change.  So it will always start with the host, then the numeric values, and end with the path, but there may, or may not be spaces in the path

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? You don't even need a regex for this as the columns are fixed and the values right-aligned. You could read the first line to determine where each column starts then directly read the substrings

Comment: I've tried a variety of different regexes, but they all incorrectly split on the spaces.  Plus the columns aren't always equally spaced, if you look there are sometimes multiple spaces delimiting values.

Comment: " Plus the columns aren't always equally spaced, if you look there are sometimes multiple spaces delimiting values" so these spaces can vary from one log line to the other? we see only 1 log line. But we are asking about different log lines versions

Comment: Regarding "the solution you figured out":  Assuming two spaces in a row never occurs in the path?

Comment: That's a valid point, I hadn't considered that.  I'll have to take another look at that, thanks

Answer (score 1):

*I reworked my answer but [Dans solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65359271/14448817) still looks better tbh*

**How:**

This will only work if the number of spaces outside of the path never changes. First I split the string and remove all empty entries from my array. Then I count the entries of my array because every entry after index 8 belongs to the path. And then I put those entries back together with spaces to complete the path.

**Code:**

```
string log = "//user@192.168.0.10/share  3.6Ti  1.0Ti  2.7Ti    28% 264402606  712347471   27%   /private/tmp/mount something here";
string[] logSplit = log.Split(' ');

//Remove empty strings
logSplit = logSplit.ToList().Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToArray();

//Put the path back together
int index = 0;
foreach(string logPart in logSplit)
{
    if(index >= 9)
    {
        logSplit[8] = logSplit[8] + " " + logSplit[index];
        logSplit = logSplit.ToList().Where(x => x != logPart).ToArray();
    }
    else
    {
        index++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It might not be guaranteed that the 'path' part never has more than 1 space at a time...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what Regex engine you're using, but I think this should give you what you need.  The trick here is the alternator, to split on either a group of spaces OR /private and then go until the end of the line.

```
\s+|(/private.*)
```

Update:
With code to strip out any blank lines.

```
var fields = Regex.Split(input, @"\s+|(/private.*)").Select(str => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str)).ToList();
```

Comment: If you use `Regex.Split` with this, it emits an empty string before and after the path.

Comment: Is that much of a problem?  You should be able to remove blank lines programmatically fairly easily.  For the empty string before, I think that is a side effect of having 2 splitters right next to each other.  For the end, it may be splitting off of the carriage return or something.  I'm not sure.

Comment: No, not difficult.  Just might be nice to include that code in the answer. The actual code you'd write could be something like: `string[] fields = Regex.Split(input, @"\s+|(/private.*)").Where(str => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)).ToArray();`

Comment: Okay, sure.  I just thought it was outside the scope of this originally, but I'm happy to include it.  I've updated my answer, which is very similar to what you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach using `Regex.Split`.

```
string[] parts = Regex.Split(input, @"\s+(?=/)");
string[] fields = Regex.Split(parts[0], @"\s+");
```

Here is a fully annotated explanation:

```
string input = @"//user@192.168.0.10/share  3.6Ti  1.0Ti  2.7Ti    28% 264402606  712347471   27%   /private/tmp/mount something here";

// Split the string into two parts where you have spaces followed by a `/`
// The second part will be the filename
// As for the first part, we will need to process it further.
string[] parts = Regex.Split(input, @"\s+(?=/)");
// parts[0]: "//user@192.168.0.10/share  3.6Ti  1.0Ti  2.7Ti    28% 264402606  712347471   27%"
// parts[1]: "/private/tmp/mount something here"

// Split the first part on spaces to get all the other fields.
string[] fields = Regex.Split(parts[0], @"\s+");
// fields[0]: "//user@192.168.0.10/share"
// fields[1]: "3.6Ti"
// fields[2]: "1.0Ti"
// fields[3]: "2.7Ti"
// fields[4]: "28%"
// fields[5]: "264402606"
// fields[6]: "712347471"
// fields[7]: "27%"

string filename = parts[1]; // parts[1] is the filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is just a tool, and even if it can do what you need... I would do it some other way that is a lot more understandable (at least for me).

Here is my proposed solution, using string splitting and some loops. It makes no assumptions about the number of spaces anywhere; multiple spaces before the start of the path are removed, and multiple spaces inside the path are kept, just in case.

```
var s = "//user@192.168.0.10/share  3.6Ti  1.0Ti  2.7Ti    28% 264402606  712347471   27%   /private/tmp/mount something    here";

var parts = s.Split(' ');
var index = 0;
// Find index of first item that starts with a single "/"
while (parts[index].StartsWith("//") || !parts[index].StartsWith("/"))
    index++;

var result = new List<string>();

// Gather non-empty items, EXcluding the one that starts with a single "/"
for (var i = 0; i < index; i++)
    if (parts[i].Length > 0) 
        result.Add(parts[i]);

// Rebuild path from all remaining items, including empty ones, adding space characters
var path = parts[index];
for (var i = index + 1; i < parts.Length; i++)
    path += " " + parts[i];

result.Add(path);
```

Result:

```
//user@192.168.0.10/share
3.6Ti
1.0Ti
2.7Ti
28%
264402606
712347471
27%
/private/tmp/mount something    here
```

Working demo, uses log string containing path with multiple spaces:
**https://dotnetfiddle.net/KMA9Xy**